# How to live stream an http url with flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm currently using the [flutter_vlc_player](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vlc_player) package to try and stream a camera view through my phone. The RTSP protocol and the http protocol in mp4 format work well but I don't see how to do it with an HTTP protocol and live (with an ip and a port).
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

"http" is just a transport protocol for video in this case, there is going to be a lot more under the hood in the file or stream itself that vlc has to try to unpack. What does "live" exactly mean?

Is it possible for you to find out exactly what the details of the codec are?

One sanity check I've used is downloading the vlc desktop player. You can "open network" from that and get a sense of what vlc thinks about the stream without all the other overhead of phone development. If it doesn't work there it probably won't ever work on phone, since the codec support on the phone vlc is unlikely to exceed the desktop.

If it does work you can pull the full details there with get info and that can give you more info to search on.

FWIW many lower end cameras use "motion jpeg" as an http-based protocol and flutter_vlc_player seems to work with that.